# Spot color in SVG embedded into PDF

Tags: pdf, svg, vector-graphics

I need to create a PDF with a vectorial graphic for a personalized packaging project. I can create the PDF with the embedded SVG but our graphic need 2 spot color for the lines so the CMYK print isnt messed up.

This screen is the PDF he created as an example
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v9wJ.jpg)
and this is the PDF i created.
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krHb1.jpg)

I tried manual editing of SVG+PHP+TCPDF, commandline Inkspace or commandline ImageMagick but i didnt find a way to insert a spot color.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Note that many renderers do not support SVG CMYK or Spot Color representations. Also, you will not see a "Spot" color in PDF in a viewer because the viewer has no knowledge of them. You should see a fallback RGB color that you also specify. RenderX XEP supports CMYK and Spot color in SVG. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968635/how-can-i-use-cmyk-in-an-svg-embeded-in-html/27991537#27991537

Comment: Thanks you, it works! I was on the right track but there was a strange problem. I mention it in case someone need it. If you do
`stroke="rgb(0,255,0) icc-color(#CMYK, 26%, 50%, 99%, 24%)"`
its a spot color, if you do
`stroke="#00FF00 icc-color(#CMYK, 26%, 50%, 99%, 24%)"`
its not!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @kevin-brown for the answer! I post a full example for reference

`<rect x="503.1" y="396.9" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0,255,0) icc-color(#CMYK, 26%, 50%, 99%, 24%)" stroke-width="0.5916" stroke-miterlimit="3.8637" width="113.4" height="396.9"/>`

Comment: Technically that is CMYK. If you have a SPOT color like Pantone, you would use something like rgb-icc(255,255,0, #SpotColor,'Pantone 355-Green C',0.30, #CMYK,.7,0,0.5,.6) in HTML and %'s in SVG. See http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Demos.Colors